# How can I put "< >" as a text in HTML?

Tags: css, html

I would like to include `<` and `>` inside of a text in HTML but I'm unable to because HTML doesn't understand that it's text.

**Is there any way to put those symbols in HTML as a text and make the editor understand it ?**

Example:

```
<div> <this is some text> </div>
```

Comment: Use the HTML entities instead - https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, simple use `&lt;` and `&gt;` like this:

```html
Use then &lt;like&gt; this

<br>
  
5 &lt; 6 = true

<br>
  
1 &gt; 2 = false
```

Your Example would be:

```html
<div>&lt;this is some text&gt;</div>
```

They are called *HTML Entity's*:

> An HTML entity is a piece of text ("string") that begins with an ampersand (&) and ends with a semicolon (;) . Entities are frequently used to display reserved characters (which would otherwise be interpreted as HTML code), and invisible characters (like non-breaking spaces)

You can check the full entity's list in [W3 Org](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) and learn more about it in the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)

Answer (score 14):

Please have a look at [html entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

[image]

You can use the entity names directly in your html.

`<p> 2 &lt; 3 </p>` will render as **2 < 3**.

likewise

`<p> 3 &gt; 2 </p>` will render as **3 > 2**.

Go and edit the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3e81hxsh/1/)**, try all the html entities and check the output

Answer (score 3):

I haven't understood your answer but as I think you want to include < or > so here is the HTML code for that `&lt;` `&gt;`.

Answer (score 3):

You Need to Escape Characters that would be seen as code:

The escape character for < is: `&lt;`

For a complete list of escape characters floow this link: https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

Answer (score 2):

to print < you must write `&lt; or &#60;` and for > write `&gt;`

like you use `&nbsp;` for white-space